# Why inverse of time delay is non causal

Tags: delay, laplace-transform

Please explain the following statement
"If \$P(s)\$ contains a time delay term, \$P^{-1}(s)\$ is non-causal". Here '\$s\$' is Laplace variable.

Can someone please explain the reason of non causality?

Comment: What is \$p^{-1}\$? Do you mean \$P^{-1}(s)\$

Comment: yes. I have corrected it

Comment: So it's \$\small P^{-1}\$ and not \$\small P^{-1}(s)\$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also explain it mathematically using the following property:

$$\begin{align}
P(s) &= \mathcal{L}\{p(t)\} \\
e^{-\tau s}P(s) &= \mathcal{L}\{p(t-\tau)\}
\end{align}$$

So that means the inverse would yield something like:

$$\begin{align}
P^{-1}(s) &= \mathcal{L}\{p_i(t)\} \\
\left(e^{-\tau s}P(s)\right)^{-1} &= e^{\tau s}P^{-1}(s) = \mathcal{L}\{p_i(t+\tau)\}
\end{align}$$

And so you see that \$p_i(t+\tau)\$ needs to look ahead in time, making it non-causal.

Answer (score 4):

"Causal" in this case means "A leads to B". **The cause is first, then comes the effect.**

Example of causality: You hit your finger with a hammer, then it hurts.

Example of non-causality: Your finger hurts now, then 5 minutes later it gets hit by a hammer.

What it means in case of a signal delay (in DSP context, but you can apply the analogy to pure math): a delay block basically does this operation: "give me a sample number N from the past". It just seems logical - you can easily get data form the past - just place old samples in a buffer. The current state of the buffer (effect) depends on the previous samples (cause).

So what can be the inverse of a delay? "Give me a sample from the future". The effect has to depend on something that has not yet happened (the future), so this situation is called non-causal.

Comment: This is an excellent explanation but Can it be explained mathematically also?